# XSL or XSLT or XSLFO: which can expand text?

Tags: xslt

Suppose I have an XML file:

```
<document>
  <title>How the West was Won</title>
  <chapter>
    Lorem Ipsum Blah .....
  </chapter>
</document>
```

Is it possible to use XSLT or XSLFO or XSL to render the title like this:

```
How the West was Won
--------------------

Lorem Ipsum Blah .....
```

How would I generate the correct number of dashes on the line following the Title?

Comment: Render it in what? PDF (XSL-FO)? Text (XSL-T)? XHTML/HTML (XSL-T)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said.. Plain Text.  What I'm after is taking the xml output of rst2html and making a formatted text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <xsl:template match="title">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  <xsl:text>
  </xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="Underline">
    <xsl:with-param name="length" select="string-length(text())"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Underline">
    <xsl:param name="length"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$length > 0">-<xsl:call-template name="Underline"><xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length - 1"/></xsl:call-template></xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>    
  </xsl:template>
```

`Underline` is a recursive template that outputs a given number of dashes.

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's very atypical, but you can also use template modes:

```
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:variable name="dashes">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="dashes"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#10;',$dashes,'&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="dashes">
        <xsl:param name="length" select="string-length() - 1"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::text()[boolean($length)]" 
            mode="dashes">
            <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length - 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have the output method set to text (though I did exclude the xml declarations from the top of my file). How can a template generate the dashes?

Answer (score 1):

This is another case where it's much simpler in XSLT 2.0.

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to string-length(title)">-</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: That is cleaner. I'm hoping to create a function that returns "=" "-" or "~" depending on how many levels deep the <title> tag is nested within other titles.